# Rails 4 includes query returns nil when there are no associated children to include in a give time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following include query and tests

```
def get_account_with_sorted_transactions(account_number, account_code, branch, from, till)
        accounts =  Account.where(account_number: account_number, account_code: account_code, branch: branch).order(:account_number)
              .includes(:transactions).where(transactions: {created_at: from .. till}).order("transactions.created_at")
    return accounts.last
end
```

I want to get accounts which have transactions in a given timestamp. I have following tests and actual results

1. when an account has no transactions then I am getting the account itself
2. when an account has transactions but not in from .. till then I am getting nil
3. when an account has transactions in from .. till then I am getting transactions (this is as expected)

What I expect from 1 and 2 is account when there are no transactions but in 2 I am getting nil.

I am new to experimental developer and any help to understand how this works would be great.

account model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'accounts'
  has_many :transactions
end
```

transaction model

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :account_number, :m_number, :registration_number, :page_number, :entry_date, :narration, :voucher_number
  # attr_accessible :debit_credit, :profit, :account_code , :balance , :branch
  self.table_name = "transactions"    
  validates :account_number, presence: true
  validates :account_code, presence: true
  belongs_to :account
```

end

Answer (score 1):

`includes` does an inner join, what you want requires an outer join, for example using a left join: `accounts left join transactions`.

```
def get_account_with_sorted_transactions(account_number, account_code, branch, from, till)
  accounts =  Account.where(
    account_number: account_number, account_code: account_code, branch: branch
  ).order(
    :account_number
  ).joins(
     'left join transactions on accounts.id = transactions.account_id'
  ).where(
     transactions: {created_at: from .. till}
  ).order("transactions.created_at")

  return accounts.last
end
```

Assuming you have `accounts.id` as primary key in `accounts` table and `transactions.account_id` as foreign key in the `transactions` table.

Comment: still getting nil back when account has no transactions.

Comment: @amjad, have you inspected your data?  Can you post your model and the relationship definitions?  If you can incorporate the migrations for these joined tables then that would also help debug the problem to a great extent.

Comment: I added both models. I am running migrations and trying to get account with transactions